# How to disconnect Metamask Wallet in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ethereum, web3js

I want to disconnect Metamask wallet using web3 in Angular.

```
//here is my wallet connect code
async connectWallet() {
 const accounts = await this.ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
 });
 this.selectedAddress = accounts[0];
}
```

kindly help me with disconnect wallet functionality
Note: I'm using Angular 12.2.14

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this [github issue fix](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8990)

const

```
async logout() {
     walletAddress = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
          params: [
            {
              eth_accounts: {}
            }
          ]
        });
    
          await window.ethereum.request({
            method: "wallet_requestPermissions",
            params: [
              {
                eth_accounts: {}
              }
            ]
          });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Naren for your response but this is not working for me on logout click it's opening connect with metamask pop up

Comment: @RushikeshGadekar Please share a working example in the question, possibly a stackblitz, it will be great to have a issue as a working example!

Comment: @RushikeshGadekar I checked the internet, I dont think you can disconnect through code, you can disconnect by refreshing the screen or by disconnecting automatically in the metamask popup

Comment: yeah, i'm getting same answer...Once a wallet is connected it's up to the user to disconnect

Comment: @RushikeshGadekar 